# Finding my own post on the wall of a Facebook event

Tags: facebook, search

A few months ago I posted something on a very active wall of a public Facebook event. It's the only thing I posted there. I might be able to remember some keywords if necessary, but I can't find a way to direct a search to match all postings on an event's wall.

The solution doesn't have to be any one-button wonder. For example, I'm willing to even look into some weird [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) scripting solutions (to get full the contents of the wall downloaded as a web page, or something like that), if such exist.

How can I find my wall post?

Comment: If you can reach past `https://graph.facebook.com/[EVENTID]/feed?access_token=[ID]` and then add the `q=[query]` then hopefully it can work. It sounds like this would need `read_stream` permissions (just a guess), so a minimal app is needed.

Comment: Just a note - accepting an answer doesn't automatically award the bounty (as you have noticed). You need to explicitly award the bounty to an answer, otherwise it will be either automatically awarded to the highest voted eligible answer **or** lost completely if there are no eligible answers.

Comment: Another note - after starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it (this is independent from accepting an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to retrieve it by using the API tools.  You first need to get your facebook username.

- You can set your user name or view it if you have already set it by going to http://www.facebook.com/username/

  Note: That this is not the user name you use to log in to Facebook.

You can now use the Graph API you can then retrieve your User Id.

- Browse to https://graph.facebook.com/%YOURUSERNAME%  so for instance mine would be https://graph.facebook.com/boconnor
- This will display your user information along with your user id. 
  [image]
- Copy the the User Id - without the quotes.
- Now browse to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.get
- Paste your user id in to the **uid** box and click *Call Method*
- This will return events that you are linked to.
  [image]
- Copy the relevent Event EID and browse to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.get
- Enter the EID in to the **Source_ids** box and click *Call Method*
- This will return the stream for that event.

I haven't quite worked out a better way of getting all the posts but you can easily copy the details out in to Notepad etc.  You can then search through these results for a search term that you used in your comment.

If I can find a better way to get your post on it's own I will post another answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this worked perfectly. I bracketed the search with `start_time` and `end_time` to a few months back, and upped the `limit` high enough (100000), then from the huge result page I searched for the string `"actor_id": [MY_ID]` and found one match - the post by me I was looking for!

Comment: @Ilari - Glad that you found your post. It is a bit tricky to find individual posts as you are not allowed to search the message text. Don't forget to award the bounty as they are no longer tied to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Barry Yes, and it was a bit surprising there didn't seem to be a way to filter the message by the `actor_id` either. I wonder if that limit could have been constructed as some sort of FQL query.

Comment: @Barry And aye, the bounty, she be yours in 5 hours time! Alas, before that them scurvy data systems, they be keepin' her captive and there ain't a way for me to release her...

Comment: @Ilari - I would have thought that there *should* be but whether you can or not is a different matter. Some things are extremely easy to find using the API other things seem to be hidden away. You have successfully brightened up my morning with your bounty comment. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Barry Are you okay with people knowing your id and username ? Just curious.

Comment: @phwd - I don't really have any problem with it. My user name is freely available. It's not the same as the user name I log in with anyway.

Comment: @Barry Always happy to brighten anyone's day. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a real pain to search the newsfeed for the post of your interest in Newsfeed, thus I have rolled out [Facebook Newsfeed Search Engine](http://searchfacebooknewsfeed.apoorv.pro) to retrieve the posts containing the Search Query while sorting them by Likes, Comments, Shares or Creation time.

Link to Web Application: http://searchfacebooknewsfeed.apoorv.pro

Link to Facebook Canvas Application: http://apps.facebook.com/search-newsfeed

[image]